# how to remove the value of an input field using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

```
<div class="info-block" ng-app="">
                            <div ng-controller="Note">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <p><b>Primary Publication: </b>
                                    {{ form_widget(form.input_ppubs, { 'attr': {'class': 'valOption'}}) }}

                                    </p>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                                <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="new input" ng-model="item.primaryPub">
                                  </div> 
                                 <button type="button" ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
                            </div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of the html input field and remove it from input upon a button click

I am able to get the code, but I don't know how to remove the code.

```
 var Note = function($scope){
            $scope.items = [];

        $scope.add = function () {


          //angular way of implementing document.getElementByID();
          pub1 = angular.element('#form_input_ppubs').val();



          $scope.items.push({ 
            primaryPub: pub1

          });
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to retrieve your items like this.  It's ugly and not the angular way.  `angular.element('#form_input_ppubs').val();`

Instead, simply reference it in your input using `ngModel`.

Declare it in your scope.

```
$scope.inputItem = null;
```

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="inputItem " />
```

**Use it in your function:**

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.push(item);

    //reset the model
    $scope.inputItem = null;
}
```

**Call it using ng-click**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addItem(inputItem)">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/sp2fq0h1/) is a demo that's showing the clearing of the input field with ng-model.

Comment: I cant create an ng-model attribute because I am using Twig(Symfony) to generate my html page. @KKKKKKKK

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
console.log($scope.items);
```

You should see an entry for primaryPub, the model for your input. Then you can target it by nulling the model, so:

```
$scope.items.primaryPub = null;
```

However you're using this inside an ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(i, item) in items">
  <input type="text" placeholder="new input" ng-model="items[i].primaryPub">
</div>
```

So your console.log (if you have more than one item in 'items') should show an array-like structure for primaryPub.